# TYPO3 extbase equals does not work

Tags: typo3, extbase

I only need to get records with type = 0 but after querying, I got all the record with all types

```
  public function findPeople() {
        $query = $this->peopleRepository->createQuery();
        $query->equals('type', 0);
        $query->setOrderings(
            array(
                'uid' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING
            )
        );
        return $query->execute();
    }


    /**
     * action people
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function listAction()
    {
        $people = $this->findPeople();
        $this->view->assign('people', $people);
    }
```

Comment: Side-note: The `findPeople` method should be inside the `PeopleRepository` class, not in the controller class...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a matching() method in the repository method:

```
  public function findPeople() {
    $query = $this->peopleRepository->createQuery();
    $query->matching($query->equals('type', 0));
    $query->setOrderings(
        array(
            'uid' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING
        )
    );
    return $query->execute();
}
```

See: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html